# How do I sort by STAT relation in yii?

Tags: php, yii, entity-relationship

I have relations as following in my User model:

```
return array(
        'images' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Images', 'owner_id'),
        'imagesCount' => array(self::STAT, 'Images', 'owner_id', 'condition' => 'approved = 1'),
        'server' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Servers', 'server_id'),
    );
```

User table is related to the Images table via owner_id.

Images model has relations as:

```
return array(
        'imageVotes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ImageVotes', 'image_id'),
        'imageTags' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ImageTags', 'image_id'),
        'owner' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'owner_id'),
        'server' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Servers', 'server_id'),
    );
```

I want to calculate the top contributors on the base of most number of images uploaded by them.

What is the CDbCriteria or CActiveDataProvider sort order of it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use virtual attributes in your sort Object of CActiveDataProvider

Your data provider should be something like this

```
$activeDataProvider =  CActiveDataProvider($userModel, array(
            'criteria' => $criteriaObject,
            'sort' => array(
                'defaultOrder'=>array('imgCount'),
                'attributes'=>array('imgCount'=>
                    array('asc'=>'(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM images WHERE owner_id = t.id)', // t.id or modelName.id
                           'desc'=>'(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM images WHERE owner_id = t.id) DESC',
                           'label'=>'Images Count',
                           'default'=>'desc',
                    )),
                )
        ));
    }
```

Refer see [`CSort`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort#attributes-detail) documentation to understand how virtual attributes and relational attributes can be used as sorting elements in your `DataProviders`